# Python Request Results In 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, web, web-scraping

I have logged into a website using python requests, but when I want to start scraping data from other pages on the site, it seems like I'm no longer authenticated?
I'm recieving a 401 error when trying to access part of the site that starts with "https://api"

I've tried using auth, proxies, but nothing is working. Works perfectly fine in Chrome. Also after I login I am able to see that my information is appearing in some of the api content, but when I do a GET on the homepage of the website I am not longer logged in.

```py
payload_login = {'email': 'me@email.com', 'password': 'password'}

with requests.Sessions() as s:
    url = 'https:/api.website.com/login"
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data)
    print r.content ###this acutally returns 200 meaning I've successfully login in
    print s.get('https://api.website.com/userProjects', auth=HttpNtlmAuth(user,pass)


Output is <Response [401]>
```

Comment: try using headers in `get` like `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}` and also try giving API site

Comment: I used the same header that Chrome is displaying for the API url and I'm still getting 401. By the way there is also an access token that I am receiving after the initial login, then I'm doing another post with that access token and it returns 200. But anything else I try to access returns 401.

Comment: could you provide the actual API link?